# Vercel Laravel POST with 404 not found

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vercel

I have deployed a test application on Vercel to submit a POST request to a planetscale database.

The application works fine under local environment, however after it is deployed, it resulted in a 404 not found when submitted to /api/add. Any idea what seems to be the issue? I have a feeling it may be my `vercel.json` but I couldn't quite figure out the issue on the doc, and the runtime functions for `vercel-php` also prevented deployment of app.css and app.js with a 404, so I have instead re-allocated `vercel-php` to "builds" instead.

https://laravelverceldeployment.vercel.app/

This is my package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "browser-sync": "^2.27.7",
        "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.39",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.4.5",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.0.12",
        "vue-loader": "^16.8.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.11.0",
        "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3": "^0.6.0",
        "@inertiajs/progress": "^0.2.7",
        "alpinejs": "^3.7.1",
        "vue": "^3.2.26"
    }
}
```

and this is my vercel.json:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        { "src": "/api/index.php", "use": "vercel-php@0.4.0" },
        { "src": "/public/**", "use": "@vercel/static" }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(css|js|images)/(.*)",
            "dest": "public/$1/$2"
        },
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "/api/index.php"
        }
    ],
    "env": {
        "APP_NAME": "laravelverceldeployment",
        "APP_ENV": "production",
        "APP_DEBUG": "false",
        "APP_URL": "https://laravelverceldeployment.vercel.app",

        "APP_CONFIG_CACHE": "/tmp/config.php",
        "APP_EVENTS_CACHE": "/tmp/events.php",
        "APP_PACKAGES_CACHE": "/tmp/packages.php",
        "APP_ROUTES_CACHE": "/tmp/routes.php",
        "APP_SERVICES_CACHE": "/tmp/services.php",
        "VIEW_COMPILED_PATH": "/tmp",
        "CACHE_DRIVER": "array",
        "LOG_CHANNEL": "stderr",
        "SESSION_DRIVER": "cookie",
        "VIEW_COMPILED_PATH": "/tmp/views",
        "SSR_TEMP_PATH": "/tmp/ssr",
        "NODE_PATH": "node"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in vercel.json, routes dest is mapped to api/index.php.

So url api/ will mapped through index.php ? try with just /add url

Comment: It doesn't work as the whole application breaks down, because the src points toward the index.php as the entry point of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Use double api prefix

```
https://<yourapp>.vercel.app/api/api
```

Above end point will point to

```
routes/api.php with prefix('api')
```